# disable sj:datepicker Struts 2

Tags: jquery, struts2, datapicker

i have folowing date picker

```
<sj:datepicker
    id="dateTo_id%{index}"  
    name="billingItems[%{index}].dateTo" 
    value="%{billingItems[#index].dateTo}"  
    displayFormat="dd.mm.yy"
    cssClass="customDatePicker" 
    buttonImage="/images/icons/calendar-blue.png"
    parentTheme="css_custom"
    disabled="true" 
/>
```

but my problem is :I can still click on the image. and open the datepicker.

[image: opening datepicker]

what is the solution for this problem ?

Edit:

Some Fields need to stay editable.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
$("button.ui-datepicker-trigger").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Or you can use this

```
$('#your_datepicker_id').datepicker('disable');
```

Comment: This is working, but now i have problem that this call disables all datepickers. On the page are some disabled, and some enabled.

Comment: You can use different `id` attributes for every datepicker and use `$("#id-of-datepicker").attr("disabled", "disabled");` instead.

Comment: @kozla13 Try using `$('#your_datepicker_id').datepicker('disable');`

Comment: Use some classes, one for disabled and another for enabled.

Comment: This is working, $('#your_datepicker_id').datepicker('disable'); the command disables the button to. Thanks